# Using ajax methods .get() and .post() in JQuery to make add to cart

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, ajax

Im working in an assignment and I want to make a "add to cart button" I tried the post and get methods but it does nothing, the code consist of 4 files explore.html, explore.js, cart.html and cart.js and the users should be allowed to click on a link while exploring products and it will appear in the cart.html

explore.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Digital Waves::Explore</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/explore.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/explore.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="/html/cart" method="POST">
            <input name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1" />
            <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="91801160" /> 
            <input name="product_name" type="hidden" value="Red Hat" /> 
            <button class="add-button" type="submit">Add to Cart!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

explore.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".add-button").click(function(){
    //alert("explore is clicked");  
    var productId = $("#productId").val();
    var productName = $("#productName").val();
    var productQuantity = $("#productQuantity").val();
    var data = {
        'product_id': productId,
        'product_name': productName,
        'quantity': productQuantity
    };

    $.post("html/cart", data, showDone);
    var showDone = function() {
        alert("I sent the data");
    };
    });

 });
```

cart.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Digital Waves::Cart</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/cart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="buttonx">I get info</button>
    <p id="x"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

cart.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttonx").click(function(){
    //alert("cart is clicked");
    $.get("../html/explore.html",function(data , status){
        $("x").html(data);
        alert("done");
    })
});
});
```

Comment: Where is your data _posting_ to? What is handling the `html/cart` request?

Comment: Also, code never _"does nothing"_. Check your browser's developer console for errors. All AJAX requests are logged in the _Network_ tab of the console too so you can confirm the request data and response is what you expect

Comment: my directory consists of project/(css,html,images,js) all the html contains html files and js contains scripts respectively and I tried the console and it gave me an error and 2 warnings

Comment: the error:
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol

Comment: Warning:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/ahmed/Desktop/edition/html/html/cart. (Reason: CORS request not http).[Learn More]

Comment: second warning:
A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element.

Answer (score 0):

As per your HTML code, you have not assigned id attribute to your input fields. You need to use id field as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <form action="/html/cart" method="POST">
            <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1" />
            <input id="product_id" name="product_id" type="hidden" value="91801160" /> 
            <input id="product_name" name="product_name" type="hidden" value="Red Hat" /> 
            <button class="add-button" type="submit">Add to Cart!</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

After this, your jQuery code should work fine. And if you have multiple add cart form, then you should use class instead of id. Hope it helps you.

Comment: What issue you are facing currently